# Javascript Extract Comments RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, comments, extract

I have a Javascript file like that

```
/**
 * My Comment Line1
 * My Comment Line2
 */
var a = 123;
/**
 * My Comment Line3
 * My Comment Line4
 */
var b = 456;
```

I am using node.js to read the file and want to extract comments in this file.

I use this regexp

```
/\/\*\*((?:\r|\n|.)*)\*\//
```

However this extracts

```
/**
 * My Comment Line1
 * My Comment Line2
 */
var a = 123;
/**
 * My Comment Line3
 * My Comment Line4
 */
```

My program have a loop to extract matched block one by one. So I want a RegExp to extract

First loop

```
/**
 * My Comment Line1
 * My Comment Line2
 */
```

Second loop

```
/**
 * My Comment Line3
 * My Comment Line4
 */
```

The rule is simply that comment block starts with `/**` and ends with `*/`. Inside a comment, all characters are allowed.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Try this :** (it'll much ANY type of comments) - Live demo here : http://regexr.com?30jrh

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

**Have a look :**

[image]

Comment: I love this answer too! This is a more generic answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYeung You're welcome, my friend! :-) It's one of the most proven regexs I've used for multi-line comment matching. It catches many "hidden" cases (like `*/` within a comment, which is still a comment, huh?) + it also get single line comments (`//`).

Comment: What about `var s = "This is a /*string*/"`? Your regex would get a false positive on that. I don't think it's possible to correctly cover all edge cases without actually parsing most of a script.

Comment: For anyone struggling with syntax errors `var commentPattern = new RegExp('(\\/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*\/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+\/)|(\/\/.*)', 'g');`

Comment: This will also have false hits on urls:
`var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";` 
Anything within quote marks should not be captured

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regular expression for that:

```
/\/\*\*(.|\n)+?\*\//
```

[And here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/4PEUc/)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Check the update, please, including the demo. (You can take off your downvote now...)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: I don't really care what "RegExr" says, this is JavaScript and the jsFiddle, y'know, *proves* it does work. Nevertheless, enable the "dotall" and "global" flags to have it work there.

Comment: It works! But why? The key point is the `?`. I don't understand... :(

Comment: @AlexYeung: The `?` after a quantifier makes it non-greedy, i.e. it will try to match as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not quite work for me. Here's what did work, in Node.js, parsing Javascript.

```
/(\/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*\/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/)|(\/\/.*)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\/\*).*?(\*\/)|(\/\/).*?(\n|\$)/s
```

Match opening and closing multiline tags and anything inbetween

```
(\/\*).*?(\*\/)
```

Or match a single line open comment that is terminated by a new or end of line

```
(\/\/).*?(\n|\$)
```

Comment: the one line match fall on lines with URLs like 'httm://www...." @Mwayi. doyou have a solution that will prevent this pleas?